# UITableViewCell height not updating when selected. using UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I'm having a hard time adjusting the height of my cell

I have a regular `UITableView` in which i return `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` for both `-tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` and `-tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:`. In each cell, i have a regular UIlabel. This works fine. However, when i select a cell, i add an image to the left of the cell, as well as make the font bigger. this sometimes can cause a line of text to flow over to the next line.

However, when the cell text overflows to 2 lines (instead of 1), it doesn't auto update the height of the cell.

How do i update the height of the cell according to the height of the content automatically?

Comment: Can you show prototype cell design

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to reload that row after changing the layout? Unless something happens that triggers the table to recalculate the size of your cell the layout won't change.

Something like

```
tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.none)
```

Comment: this kind of works the second time i select the cell, but not the first time. hmm.. is this expected? i'm assuming you mean: something like first call `beginUpdates:`, then call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`, and then call `endUpdates`?